# What does the Magento 2 ko scope: 'minicart_content' reference?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, mini-cart, knockoutjs

Does anyone know what scope: 'minicart_content' references? I have a couple of ideas, I have been trying to track this down. I am converting flat HTML templates to Magento. when I  do

```
<p data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></p>
```

The subtotal outputs with a `<span class="price">$0.00</span>` inside of the `<p/>` tag

I only want the values from the cart.

Within my theme, I am using the file
Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is telling knockoutJS to use the `minicart_content` ui component as the base object. What this means is that `data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')` resolves to the `getCartParam` method found in `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js` which is the `component` element of `minicart_content` as defined in `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`.

Comment: Thank you, would the <span/> tag encapsulating the subtotal in the output happen to be coming from `Magento_Checkout/view/base/web/js/price-box.js` ?

Comment: I don't actually have the code you posted in my installation (perhaps you're using an older version?) but in my installation it works like this: the subtotal `<span>` comes from `Magento_Directory/Model/Currency.php` in the `formatPrecision` method. The html string returned by this method ends up in the `cart` section of the `CustomerData` object (`Magento_Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js`) and is printed out in `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/subtotal/totals.html`.